# Dynamically populated highcharts data and database storing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to store highcharts data from a dynamically created chart in a database and get that data back into highcharts. To store the data in the database I create a string like this:

```
var chartPoints = "";

var series = chart.series;

for( var i = 0; i < series.length; i++ ) {
    var numberOfPoints = series[i].data.length;     //Get number of points

    for( var n = 0, length = numberOfPoints; n < length; n++ ) {
        chartPoints += '[' + series[i].points[n].x + ',' + series[i].points[n].y + '],';

    }
    chartPoints += '/,';
}
```

This creates a string like this "[1470009600000,0],[1471219200000,0],/,[1470009600000,-1],[1471219200000,-1],/," x values are dates. This is 2 series with an "/" between the series. The 2 series have 2 datapoints each. All the datapoints have an x and a y value. This is just an example with a low number of points and series in order to make it work.

The problem is that i don't know how i should push the values from that string back into highcharts. I know i can dynamically add series to highcharts like this:

```
chart.addSeries({                        
    name: "Test",
    data: [
            [x, y], 
            [x, y]  
        ]
});
```

But i don't know how to do that with a string like this. I tried to create an array with multiple dimensions out of the string in order to push values from that with some loops, but i couldn't get it right. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why you return slash and data as a string instead of native JSON?

Comment: Show me how you would have done it

Comment: You can parse your data using some basic js functions but the true is that it is not the best formatting for Highcharts, like Sebastian mentioned it would be much better to use JSON instead of your string. http://jsfiddle.net/y3quyg4n/1/

Comment: @Koiski we do not have a knowledge how to load data from database and convert to your string. Could you paste your code? (Is it PHP or other code?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about storing the series data as a json string, then parsing it back into an object and passing it into the data param?  You could do something like:

```
var sData = JSON.stringify(chart.series[0].options.data);
```

and store sData as a string.  Then to load back into highcharts do:

```
var oData = JSON.parse(json_string_from_db);

chart.addSeries({                        
    name: "Test",
    data: oData
});
```

or

```
chart.series[0].setData(oData);
```

I made a plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/myGoss?p=preview which sets the data using `setData()`  but could load the data when the series was created.

Comment: Doesn't work... Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Try the change above, use `chart.series[0].options.data` to get the data. Check the plunk i made to test it out.